# Coroutines and scope

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Using a coroutine for a delay after an event is received.
After the delay I should be resetting a private Boolean '_isActive' to false but this never happens.
Is this possibly due to a scoping issue?

here is my code

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System;

IEnumerator coroutine;
bool _isActive;

void Awake()
{
    _isActive = false;
    coroutine = MyDelay();
}

private bool MyEventhandler(IEvent evt)
{
    StartCoroutine(coroutine);
    _isActive = true;
    Debug.Log("Yes event received");
}

IEnumerator MyDelay()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2.0f);
    Debug.Log("Yes delay complete");
    _isActive = false;//private class variable _isActive does not get reset to false
}


void Update(){
    Debug.Log(" _isActive = " + _isActive);//_isActive gets set to true but never gets reset to false!!
}
```

Comment: Are you missing your class declaration?

Comment: Have you tried `StartCoroutine(MyDelay())`?

Comment: @z3nth10n He has `StartCoroutine` in the `MyEventhandler` function

Comment: Do you see "Yes delay complete" in the log?

Comment: Ok think I found the issue. Needed to set _isActive = true BEFORE calling my delay Coroutine.

Comment: @eco_bach no, it won't work the same, read my answer to understand what's happening in your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters, your code can't compile, you're not returning a `bool` value in `MyEventhandler`.

But that's not why your code isn't working, it's because you never create a **new** coroutine after the first call, you always try to re-start the same coroutine instance.

You should do this:

```cs
private bool MyEventhandler(IEvent evt) {
    StopCoroutine(coroutine); //OPTIONAL - read below
    coroutine = MyDelay();
    StartCoroutine(coroutine);
    _isActive = true;
    Debug.Log("Yes event received");
    return _isActive;
}
```

`StopCoroutine(coroutine);` is used to stop the previously running coroutine, so that every time the event is raised, the delay will be reset to 2 seconds. If you don't want to reset the delay timer before it's ended, even if other events are raised, then don't stop the Coroutine.

Then, `coroutine = MyDelay();` is used to create a new reference to another instance of the same `IEnumerator` method, so that when you start it you're starting it from the start and trying to restart an instance that's already hit the end and won't do nothing at all.

I'd move anyway the `_isActive = true;` at the start of `MyDelay()`, so that is clear, by reading only that method, what that coroutine will do.

EDIT: I'll try to explain why you need to create a new reference to get it to work.

`IEnumerator` in Unity has only two accessible and working elements: `MoveNext()` and `Current` (`Reset()` doesn't work).
It's thanks to that `MoveNext()` that Unity can make coroutines work.

An `IEnumerator` works this way: it's a collection of objects which can be accessed only in sequential way: the first time it's initialized, `Current` points to an element before the first object, then to access the next element, you need to call `MoveNext()`, and so on. Outside Unity, you can reset the current object (making it go back to the first element) with `Reset()`, but as I said this doesn't work in Unity.

And that's how coroutines are executed in Unity: when started, Unity executes all code until it reaches a `yield return` instruction - this tells Unity from which point it needs to restart execution of the remaining code. Basically, if you have code like this:

```cs
IEnumerator MyCoroutine() {
    // Do stuff #1
    yield return null;
    //Do stuff #2
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
    //Do stuff #3
}
```

what happens is this:

- `Coroutine()` is started with `StartCoroutine`: at this point, the enumerator is positioned before the first element
- The first `MoveNext()` is called on the enumerator, so `Current` becomes the `Do Stuff #1` and gets executed
- `yield return null` - at this point, Unity is instructed to interrupt the execution of the code until a frame is passed, the execution will start at the end of the next `Update` callback
- After the next `Update()` is executed, Unity makes a `MoveNext()` on `MyCoroutine()`, which will make `Current` equal to `Do Stuff 2`, and will execute it
- `yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);` is hit - now Unity is instructed to execute `MoveNext()` after 1 second of time (so it will try to fit it between two Unity's callbacks by checking the difference of time using `Time.deltaTime`)
- 1 second passes, `MoveNext()` is called, and `Do Stuff #3` is executed.

Now the coroutine has reached the end, but the `IEnumerator` is not gone for good, if you started the coroutine by way of a reference. Because the reference remains the same unless is assigned again, so even if you try to use `StartCoroutine(reference)`, Unity will execute immediately a `MoveNext()` on that enumerator, but there're no elements after the last `Current` you hit, so it won't execute anything because there's nothing to execute.

Comment: StopCoroutine may not be needed I think. It’d depend what is expected. If a press resets the coroutine, then yes. If a press should be ignored if a coroutine already running then no and different logic is needed.

Comment: @Everts you're right, I thought of it as if OP wanted to add a delay of 2 seconds everytime the event is raised - I'll edit the answer to add this very valid point you raised

Comment: Thanks for the well thought out answer.